# Button not causing postback

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

I've got a Button, with the corresponding `aspx` being this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="checkall" OnClientClick="setAllWeeks(true);" 
    AutoPostBack="true" Text="Check All" />
```

This is because the logic I want to happen for this particular button on the server side is validation that occurs every time in the `Page_Load` event, and additionally, I want a Javascript function to be called first. However, when I click the button, it doesn't seem to cause a postback the first time, only the second time that it's posted.

How can I guarantee that the client-side function is executed first, and then a postback is generated?

Comment: Could you pls show us the generated html?

Comment: I encountered this when validation on the page had failed. Might be worth having a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following code:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="checkall" OnClientClick="return setAllWeeks(true);" 
    AutoPostBack="true" Text="Check All" />
```

And inside the setAllWeeks() function do the following :

```
function setAllWeeks(val) {

    //If everything all right
    If(True)
    {
      //Do something
      return true;   
    }
    else
      return false;
}
```

If the function behaviors is all right return true else return false.

Note: All paths of the function should return a value(Boolean value).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a few times. The cause was that my function specified in OnClientClick returned 'false'.

Hoe does that 'setAllWeeks' look like?
Maybe it's returning false?

Comment: ok, sry, I'm wrong. There would have to be 'return setAllWeeks(true);' as your OnClientClick.